# Libreoffice count with condition and grouping

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice, countif

I need to count the number of non empty cells in column Foo grouped by column Subject (Using LibreOffice)

```
Subject     Foo
subject_1    20
subject_1  
subject_1     2
subject_2     4
subject_2 
subject_3
```

So basically my output need to be:

```
subject_1  2
subject_2  1
subject_3  0
```

`countA` does the job of counting non empty cells, but cannot group.
I tried `countif`, but I doesn't accept the conditions I put on it.

How can I do a count given a condition (empty cell in my case) and grouping (by the value of another column)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a way to do it.

Supposing you have your data in the columns A,B and the unique list of subjects in the column D, the following formula does the job.

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$4000,"<>",$A$2:$A$4000, D2)`

Basically it's a count with two conditions which both need to be true.
The first condition checks if the Bi cell is not empty, the second checks if the Ai cell corresponds to the subject in the Di cell (which is the unique subject)

This formula can be set in cell E2 and slide it down, so the last part `D2` will point to the corresponding subject in Di.

Answer (score 0):

With your countif, what params did you try?

using len(cell)<>0 should do the trick.

Comment: yup, this will count all non empty cells and return me 3 (as `countA` does), what I want is this 3 occurences to be grouped by the first column, so I get [2, 1, 0]

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a Pivot table for this in all fairness, unless this isn;t an option?